# How to validate non breaking space in CKEditor

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

Well i have the [ckeditor](/questions/tagged/ckeditor) in my page when the user keep entering spaces only, then the empty validation meant that it is not empty because it contains the `&nbsp;` inside the `<p></p>` so the editor content is not empty but when we see that content in html it will display nothing because its non breaking spaces.

Now issue is that how validate that inside the editor no one can put like spaces like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'trim' to remove all whitespace from the beginning and end of the input

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

you can then add some logic to see if the trimmed string is empty or not, before it is passed to whatever you use to save/display the data.
Use .text() to remove tags first.

e.g.

```
if($(myContent).text().trim() != "") //process myContent
else //throw error
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLzoL81u/

Comment: well @MrEvers you are right but creditor return this type of content of the spaces <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> now how to validate all this in jquery

Comment: .text() removes tags, updated my answer with a fiddle